# How to write ascii symbol into char table?

Tags: c, char, ascii

Let's assume that I've got such a table:

```
char *table = "abcdef\n";
```

How can I put '\n' as decimal subsituide (eg. in hex I put \x0D, in oct I put \015, but what about decimal?)

Comment: You can't express character literals in decimal in C.

Comment: Do you mean `\n` instead of `/n`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'/n'` is not a character control, but a multi-character constant, so I assume you're talking about `'\n'` instead.

There is no escape notation in decimal, so simply use `\n`, the octal (`\012` or `\12`) or the hexadecimal (`\x0a`) escape notation.

[**Learn more about escape sequences**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can define one Macro `#define NEW_LINE "\n"`.
then use `char *table = "abcdef"NEW_LINE;`
And if you `cout <<table;` out put will be:
`abcdef`
`_`

It means the value of table is `"abcdef\n"`